# ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: cause of mAllowStartForeground false

Tags: android

Hi am working on media player service in which am calling create Notification function in which if player playing am calling startForeground(1, notification.build());

but for android Q we can call it directly as there is exception of ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException: Service.startForeground() not allowed due to mAllowStartForeground false.

For this I started using worker which is working fine but with worker new issue raised as after few minutes of playing the audio it stops with same exceptions.

So I checked official documentation over there its mentioned that we have to pass setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityLaunchAllowed with true as parameter to pending intent.

With following code its giving error of Cannot resolve method 'setActivityOptions' in 'PendingIntent.

Please check the following code any help really appreciated.

```
private void buildNotification()
{
    int notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
    PendingIntent play_pauseAction = null;

    if (player.isPlaying())
    {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause;
        //create the pause action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(1);
    }
    else// if (playbackStatus == PlaybackStatus.PAUSED)
    {
        notificationAction = android.R.drawable.ic_media_play;
        //create the play action
        play_pauseAction = playbackAction(0);
    }
    
    Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_pause); 

    // Create a new Notification
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Hide the timestamp
            .setShowWhen(false)
            // Set the Notification style
            .setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
                    // Attach our MediaSession token
                    .setMediaSession(mediaSession.getSessionToken())
                    // Show our playback controls in the compat view
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
            // Set the Notification color
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.purple_200))
            // Set the large and small icons
            .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_headset)
            // Set Notification content information
            .setContentText("Artist")
            .setContentTitle("Album")
            .setContentInfo("Title")
    
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3))
            .addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2))
            .setOngoing(true);
    
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        String channelId = "Your_channel_id";
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,"Channel human readable title", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
    }
    
    ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        options.setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityLaunchAllowed(true);
    }
    
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    
    notificationIntent .putExtra("callType","NOTIFICATION");
    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent  = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,notificationIntent , PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        pendingIntent.setActivityOptions(options);
    }

//        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent ,);

    if(player.isPlaying())
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            startForeground(345, notificationBuilder.build(), ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK);
        } else {
            startForeground(345, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        stopForeground(false);
        mNotificationManager.notify(345, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

```
private void buildNotification()
{
StorageUtil storage = new StorageUtil(getApplicationContext());
String coverImageUrl = storage.loadAlbumCoverImage();

    Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
            .putBoolean("isPlaying", player.isPlaying())
            .build();
    
    OneTimeWorkRequest myWorkRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .build();
    
    WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(myWorkRequest);

}
```

Woker class:

```
public MyWorker(@NonNull Context context,@NonNull WorkerParameters params)
{
super(context, params);
this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork()
{
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setShowWhen(false)
.setSilent(true)
.setStyle(new androidx.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle()
.setMediaSession(NNService.mediaSession.getSessionToken())
.setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2))
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
.setContentText("Artist")
.setContentTitle(activeAudio.getAlbumName())
.setContentInfo(activeAudio.getFileName())
.setAutoCancel(false)
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "previous", playbackAction(3,context))
.addAction(notificationAction, "pause", play_pauseAction)
.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "next", playbackAction(2,context))
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
.setOngoing(true);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            String channelId = "345";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(channelId);
        }
    
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AudioBookPlayerActivity.class);
    
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("callType","NOTIFICATION");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
    
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 202,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

/\*        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
mNotificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);\*/

        if (isPlaying)
        {
            createForegroundInfo(notificationBuilder.build());
        }
        else
        {
            stopForeground(false);
            mNotificationManager.notify(345, notificationBuilder.build());
        }
        
        return Result.success(); // or Result.failure() on failure
    }
    
    private ForegroundInfo createForegroundInfo(Notification notification)
    {
        return new ForegroundInfo(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }
```

With the both the approach am unable to get the desired result of keeping player ongoing..

Following code for android manifest:

```
<service
        android:name=".helper.player.NNService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        tools:ignore="ExportedService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.media.AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY" />
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

and permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
```

Comment: Did you tried PendingIntent.getActivity method that accepts ActivityOptions as a parameter ?

Comment: @jesto paul I just tried your suggestion but for  PendingIntent.getActivity the fourth parameter of options to be of type Bundle correct me if I am wrong. and with that we cant pass setPendingIntentBackgroundActivityLaunchAllowed

Comment: just out of curiosity can you try to add
        if (SDK_INT >= 31) {
            builder.foregroundServiceBehavior = Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE
        }

and try if it works?